# Laravel 5 - Updating one to many relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a one to many relation with `affiliates` table.

***User Model:***

```
public function affiliates() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Affiliate');
    }
```

***Affiliate Model:***

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

The `affiliates` are other `users` which is selected from a select box in a form.

The schema of Affiliates is below

```
Schema::create('affiliates', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('affiliate_id');
        });
```

I want to update the multiple affiliates selected from the form. Please give me an example to update the existing records or create new.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$input = [2, 3];
$affiliates = User::whereIn('id', $input)->get();

// Delete old affiliates
Affiliate::whereUserId($user->id)->delete();

// Add new affiliates
foreach($affiliates as $affiliate)
    $user->affiliates()->save(new Affiliate(['user_id' => $user->id, 'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id]));
```

Where

- `$user` is the user that will get new affiliates.
- `$input` The form input that contains the ids of the users that will become affiliates of `$user`.

Make sure `user_id` and `affiliate_id` columns are fillable (not guarded) in your `Affiliate` model or you will get an `MassAssignmentException` exception.